# Let users pay for push notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a service where users can register for news which they get via sms or email. The user has a monthly subscription (base price) + price per items.

Now I want to bring this service onto the iOS. The user can register for the same information and he will get push notifications if some news are released. I want that the user will pay for the content as they already do at the moment when receiving news via email or sms. Can I let the users pay via web (paypal) to charging their accounts balance or have I to use the in-app-purchase because they receive the information via push notifications?
What is the best way and more important: which way is the right (by apple provided) way?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use In-App purchase, OR you could host the paypal payment out of process, however you won't be allowed to link to it from within the app, which is pretty useless.

Basically, to avoid lots of trouble (and to make payment collection easier), use apple's in-app purchases to create a subscription for 'push notifications'.  You can then contact your server with the in-app purchase receipt and the device info, and start sending notifications to that device from your server.